# NO such file or directory error when doing insmod in Android Kernel

Tags: android, android-source

I followed the steps in the forum (http://www.schaeuffelhut.de/wordpress/?p=237&cpage=1#comment-384) to get the linux kernel source and and cross compile my module. The kernel version of the google nexus one is exactly the same as in the forum. I initially tested with my test module hello-1.ko which got installed on the android device successfully. But when I am installing my module ec.ko on the android device using insmod, I get the following error.

> apurva@apurva-Inspiron-1464:~/$ adb shell
>     $ cd sdcard/data/ec
>     $ ls
>     ec.ko
>     $ su
>     # insmod ec.ko
>     insmod: init_module 'ec.ko' failed (No such file or directory)
>     #

It is clear that the file ec.ko is present. But I am not sure why it is not picking the file. I did the same thing for hello-1.ko and it gets insmod pretty fine. There is no permission issue, and ec.ko gets the same permission as was obtained by hello-1.ko.

Now this bring me to the question, Are there certain limitations of a kernel module in an android device because this module gets insmod in Ubuntu. Next action for me is to go for a hit and trial method and check what lines in ec.c is causing the problem. Meanwhile if you some suggestion, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the dmesg log to see something can help you.I have also encountered the same problem.Following is how I solved this problem.
I installed my module on the android device by using insmod command,but I got the same error message like you.I checked the dmesg at that time，and I got this:Unknown symbol "XXX"(I have forgotten the function name.).I used the command —— cat /proc/kallsyms |grep "XXX" to find this symbol,but I found nothing.The reason for this problem is the function have been deprecated in AndroidM.Finally,I fixed this problem by annotating the function.

Comment: This solved a similar problem for me. There was another .ko on which I had a depency that failed to export a few symbols.  I added a few "EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(XXX);" to that code and I was able to load my module properly. Thanks!